# Rails: error: database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger

The Rails application I'm developing is running fine on my local machine (MAC). When I upload it to the server (Centos 6.2 Linux, with Rails 3.2.3 and Passenger installed), and try to start the application (by entering the URL into my browser), I get the following error message:

> Ruby (Rack) application could not be started There appears to be a
>   database problem.
>
> Your application's database configuration file might be written
>   incorrectly. Please check it and fix any errors.
>
> The database server may not be running. Please check whether it's
>   running, and start it if it isn't.
>
> Error message:
>       database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified) Exception class:
>       ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified

Note that when I ran `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`, both of these tasks ran fine and the databases are created and migrated properly.

Following is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: acme_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ***********
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: acme_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: *****************
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where is the production configuration?

Comment: I took production out. Does Passenger assume Production? I thought that dev is the default, unless I specify otherwise.

Comment: I think so. But I never used Passenger. Specify your production db and do `rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=production` and then see if it works.

Comment: I think I'm making progress. I restored production to database.yml, and ran rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=produciton. The database production was created OK, but when I tried to run the app, I got the following message: We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Comment: Hit return too soon... I checked the production.log and it's empty. The development.log file did not have any recent activity on it.

Comment: Try change your production environment config with `config.log_level = :debug`, restart the server and see if you have anything in your log now

Comment: No change. On the server, I only have a development.log file and it has not changed since yesterday. A side question: how does Rails manage the log files? when I'm on my local machine, the log files can change, and when I upload my changes, the log files will be wiped out. The obvious answer would be to exclude the log files, but I was wondering if Rails has a built-in mechanism to manage this.

Answer (score 3):

Phusion Passenger defaults to the "production" environment, [as documented](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rack_env). It looks like you assume "development". In that case, set "RackEnv development".

Comment: Good point.  Note, we have also noticed that when copy and pasting a database.yml from a local editor into a terminal, sometimes the spaces/tabbing does not translate properly, so ensure, too, that your YAML file is structured properly (as on the local machine).